# Find the supremum of a set involving minimum function

Tags: calculus

Let $a$ be a positive number. Set
$$
A=\{(2a-x)(\min\{1,x\})^2:0<x<2a\}.
$$
Observe that $A$ is upper bounded by $2a$. I am trying to find the supremum (the least upper bound) of $A$ but I cannot.
I am grateful to all kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\underline{\text{If $2a\leq1$}}$: Then $\min\{1,x\}=x$ for $0<x<2a$, and therefore
$$
A=\left\{(2a-x)x^2:0<x<2a\right\}.
$$
As $(2a-x)x^2$ is continuous we have $\sup A=\max_{x\in[0,2a]}(2a-x)x^2$, so we only need to observe that the function $(2a-x)x^2$ attains its maximum $\frac{32}{27}a^3$ at $x=\frac{4}{3}a$.

$\underline{\text{If $2a>1$}}$: Then, for $x>1$,
$$
(2a-1)\left(\min\{1,1\}\right)^2=2a-1\geq 2a-x=(2a-x)\left(\min\{1,x\}\right)^2.
$$
This tells us that
$$
\sup A=\sup \left\{(2a-x)\left(\min\{1,x\}\right)^2:0<x\leq1\right\}.
$$
As $\min\{1,x\}=x$ for $0<x\leq1$ the same reasoning as above gives us
$$
\sup A=\max_{x\in[0,1]}(2a-x)x^2.
$$
And we find that if $\frac{4}{3}a\leq1$ then again $\sup A=\frac{32}{27}a^3$, and if $\frac{4}{3}a>1$ then $\sup A=(2a-1)\cdot1^2=2a-1.$

Answer (score 1):

Consider two cases.

1. $2a < 1$

In this case $\min\{1,x\} = x$ and $A = \{ (2a-x)x^2 : 0<x<2a \}.$
Just find maximal value of the function $f(x) = (2a - x)x^2$ using derivative.

$f'(x) = -x^2 + 2x(2a-x) = -3x^2 + 4xa = x(-3x+4a)$

So you have two critical points $x=0$ and $x=\frac{4a}{3}.$ Discard $x=0$ as $f(0)=0$ and $f$ also takes positive values when $0<x<2a.$ On the other hand taking into account the sign of the derivative one may conclude that the function $f$ increases for $0<x<\frac{4a}{3}$ and decreases for $\frac{4a}{3} < x < 1$. So $x=\frac{4a}{3}$ is the point of maximum. And $\max\limits_{0<x<2a} f(x) = f(\frac{4a}{3}) = \frac{32a^3}{27}.$

Hence $\sup A = \max A = \frac{32a^3}{27}$.

2. $2a \ge 1$

Here you have $\min\{ 1,x\} = x,$ when $0<x<1$ and $\min\{ 1,x\} = 1,$ when $1 \le x<2a$.

You can consider two functions $$f_1(x) = (2a-x)x^2 \qquad \mbox{for} \qquad 0<x<1$$ and 
$$f_2(x) = 2a-x \qquad \mbox{for} \qquad 1\le x < 2a.$$

Taking into account the previous case you can state that $\max\limits_{0<x<1} f_1(x) = f_1(\frac{4a}{3}) = \frac{32a^3}{27}$ if $\frac{4a}{3} < 1$ and $\sup\limits_{0<x<1} f_1(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to 1-0}f_1(x) = 2a - 1$ if $\frac{4a}{3}\ge 1$. Also you can say that $\frac{32a^3}{27} \ge 2a - 1$ when $\frac13 \le \frac{4a}{3} < 1$.

The function $f_2$ is decreasing, because $f'_2(x) = -1 < 0.$ So $\max\limits_{1\le x < 2a} f_2(x) = f_2(1) = 2a - 1.$

Therefore in the second case $\sup A = \max A = \frac{32a^3}{27}$ if $\frac{4a}{3} < 1$ and $\sup A = 2a-1$ if $\frac{4a}{3} \ge 1.$

Summarizing, we get

$$\sup A = \frac{32a^3}{27} \qquad \mbox{when} \qquad 2a < \frac 32$$
$$\sup A = 2a-1 \qquad \mbox{when} \qquad 2a \ge \frac 32$$

Answer (score 0):

We can write $A=f((0,2a))$ where
$$
f(x):=(2a-x)x^2\chi_{[0,1]}(x)+(2a-x)\chi_{(1,2a]}(x).
$$
As $f$ is a continuous function and $[0,2a]$ is compact you'll have $$\sup A=\sup_{x\in(0,2a)}f(x)=\max_{x\in[0,2a]}f(x).$$

To maximize $f$ you might separate the cases $1\leq 2a$ and $1>2a$ and perform the usual analysis. A quicker way to go would be to notice that $2a-x$ is decreasing so
$$
\max_{x\in[0,2a]}f(x)=\max_{x\in[0,\min\{1,2a\}]}(2a-x)x^2,
$$
which reduces the question to the easy problem of maximizing a $3$-degree polynomial in a closed interval.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Could you give an explicit value of $\max_{x\in[0,2a]}f(x)$?

Comment: Really a downvote? Could the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: I cannot follow your answer. Please make your solution clearer. Thanks.

Comment: When you don't understand an answer you ask for an explanation. Downvotes intend to denote that an answer is wrong, not an answer or offensive. If you don't understand some point then maybe I can help you, but I think the answer can't be clearer.

Comment: Your answer is unclear. I am waiting for the explicit value of the supremum. If you could make the question clearer I will upvote and accept your answer. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: You mean 'make the answer clearer'. And no, it is already clear. If you want to find the value then work out the last expression. Or you don't know how to calculate the maximum of a polynomial of degree $3$ in an interval?

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Could you make clear why  we have $\max_{x\in[0,2a]}f(x)=\max_{x\in[0,\min\{1,2a\}]}(2a-x)x^2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50332/discussion-between-blind-and-mathbeing).

Comment: I've added another answer to those like you who don't feel this one is clear enough.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help.